# What .sty files do I need to successfully run pdflatex on .tex produced from nbconvert?

Tags: packages, workflow

Allegedly, one can produce pdf files from ipython notebooks by first producing a .tex file from nbconvert (http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/nbconvert.html#nbconvert)

However, I run into a `` ! LaTeX Error: File `import.sty' not found. `` when trying to run pdfLaTeX on the `.tex` files I produce using `nbconvert`.  What are the .sty files or packages I need to install in order to produce nice PDF files from ipython notebooks?

Comment: One would need to see the preamble of the .tex file:  it contains the list of all packages that are required to compile. Import.sty is part of the TeX Live as well as the MiKTeX distribution, but not necessarily installed by default. The simplest way to go is to use the package manager of the distribution

Comment: The answer to your question is '*whichever packages give you that error message*'. I did a quick test and didn't have to install any packages, but I have a complete TeX Live distribution. A basic MikTeX installation may miss several packages, but as Bernard says, use the Package manager to install these.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, that makes sense.  I'm on Ubuntu 13.04, and installed TeX Live per http://askubuntu.com/questions/163682/how-do-i-install-the-latest-tex-live-2012  I probably don't have pdflatex properly configured to point to that distribution.  Once I get it sorted, I'll post an answer in case anyone else runs into this same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. Solved by installing pdf-latex-extra (on ubuntu, as the OP)

Comment: This mostly depends on the TeX distribution you're using and without specifying which one, this answer doesn't help.

Comment: info added (ciao Enrico!)